# Python socket issue on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking, sniffer

I'm trying to catch packets on windows 10. 
I used instruction from official document page:

```
import socket

# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

# receive a package
while True:
    print(s.recvfrom(65565))    

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

Previously I was able to catch them, but right now i see only some dummy UDP packets

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause: 
socket.gethostbyname() returns IP of Ethernet adapter(I don't use such, but it become active after system update).
So disabling it fix the issue.